# android runonuithread() function not executing

Tags: android

I am developing an application that uses a third party tts, named flite. I am doing something like as the tts speaks a sentence. I want to highlight each word as it is spoken. For this, I have managed to get the word-level callbacks from the tts.
the workflow is like this--"speak text" button pressed.It starts the tt
s service and then it sends the text to the flite tts which is in C language and has been combined with the app.
Now, from C code, after every word I make two callbacks to two different java activities:
one to the tts service to speak the word
second to my test java activity to highlight the word.
I am successfully getting the word-level callbacks in my test activity but after that I am not able to do any UI work.

Following is the code that I execute when I get the callback:
this is the function that gets called from the C code.

```
private void WordCallback(int isword) {// from
    // callback
    if (isword == -1) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "its not a word");
    } else if (isword == -2) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "yeah..its the end");
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "its word no " + isword);

        int word = isword;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "highlightwords");
        highlightwords(isword);

        if (isword == 4) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "in if");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "thread started");
                    try {
                        Flitetest.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "run on ui");
                                textview.setText("#" + isword);
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }    
}
```

FliteTest is the name of the activity.
the Log prints till "Thread started" but the code inside runonuithread() is never executed and there is no error also.

Also, If write `textview.settext("something")` without the thread and runonuithread(), it gives the error:

`fatal signal 11(sigsegv) at 0x6fc64e87(code=1), thread 20292(SynthThread)`.

What is the reason for that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

On Android `ICS (4.0+)`, if you have `android:anyDensity=false` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,  *AND* you have forced GPU rendering enabled on your ICS phone. This is a problem for native Android apps as well.
Your options are to either not use the `android:anyDensity=false` options, or to disable forced GPU rendering on the phone. Since you can't really control the latter on other people's phones, the former seems like the best solution. Remember to use the '`dp`' suffix on all your `dimensions` then.